# i have run into this error "props map error "

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-map-gl

Hi everyone am still learning react by building a dark Mode toggle button that on clicked it changes the mode from light to dark and vice versa. I have ran into a problem when i tried mapping through the state and displaying the data in form of a card(incomplete though)

code structure and the errors

[image: main app component]

[image: the Darkmode component]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`props` is an object. `map` is a method of an array. You probably meant `props.individuals.map`

Answer (score 0):

You have to write this `props.individuals.map` instead of `props.map`

Answer (score 0):

do

```
const individual = props.individuals.map(person=>....
```

or

```
const DarkMode = ({individuals}) =>{
    const individual = individuals.map(person=>....
```